# mongodb update document method

Tags: mongodb, scala

I would like to create an generic update method, that take as input the Object _id and a String (Json) that correspond to the update to do.

I need to transform the inputDocument variable to a Document type to be passed in the update method

I need to have this generic way of typing because i would like to use this method on any field of the collection,

How can i achieve this ?

```
  def updateField(_id : String, inputDocument : String): Future[UpdateResult] = {

/* inputDocument = {"key" : value}*/

    val mongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
    val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("databaseName")
    val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection("collectionName")

    val updateDocument = Document("$set" -> inputDocument)

    collection
      .updateOne(Filters.eq("_id", BsonObjectId(_id)), updateDocument)
      .toFuture()
  }
```

Comment: Why not use a **Document** instead of a **Map**?

Comment: a Document is created from a Map i think, non ?

Comment: A **Document** is similar to a **Map**. But, it ensures that all its values can be written into Mongo.

Comment: How can i achieve this ? 
I receive a payload {"key" : value} that I parse to Map[String,Any]

Comment: Do not parse into a **Map[Sring, Any]**. If it is a `JSON` the either parse it into a case class that you can control or if you can receive any kind of data, then parse it into a JSON object which you can transform into a document. But that its outside the scope of this question.

Comment: I have edited my question in consequence, can you give me the way to do it from a json string to Document ?

Comment: First, I would suggest you to use a **Json** library. _like [circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/)_, to parse the **String** into a valid `JsonObject` then transform that into the document _(each library provides a way of doing the transformation)_. Or, actually, I am pretty sure the MongoDB java driver already provides a way to parse any json into a bson.

Comment: `Any` is quite always a symptom there is something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thinking about handling the inputDocument variable was not correct.
It is indeed necessary to transform the input into Document.
org.mongodb.scala.bson.collection.mutable.Document has an apply() method to parse a json string to a Document. 
Thank you all for your comments.

```
  def updateField(_id : String, inputDocument : String): Future[UpdateResult] = {

    /* inputDocument = {"key" : value}*/

    val mongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
    val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("databaseName")
    val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection("collectionName")

    val updateDocument = Document("$set" -> Document(inputDocument))

    collection
      .updateOne(Filters.eq("_id", BsonObjectId(_id)), updateDocument)
      .toFuture()
  }
```